# Head & tail using awk in bash script

Tags: bash, awk, gawk

I'm here with another question about awk.

I have to use awk command inside bash script using script arguments.

All I have to do is: head & tail every file, that is given in script arg

Example: ./script.sh 5 3 sampledata*

(where sampledata* are files: sampledata, sampledata1, sampledata2....; 5 - is for 'head', 3 - is for 'tail').

All I have is:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk -v h="$1" -v t="$2" 'NR<=h && NR>=t' "$3"
```

That works but only for the first file from sampledata* ! ):

How can I make it work for every file from sampledata* ???
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Search awk refs for `FNR`.

Comment: I've tried to set FNR==1, nothing happens

Comment: _FNR is the current record number in the current file. FNR is incremented each time a new record is read. It is reinitialized to zero each time a new input file is started._  In other words, use `FNR` instead of `NR`, so that the record numbers restart from 1 with each new file.

Comment: your tail logic is wrong as well.

Comment: Can you explain, please?

Comment: Your requirements are unclear, either your logic is wrong or you misunderstand what head and tail do or you do understand but have used the terms poorly. Is 3 the line number you want to tail from or the number of lines you want to tail at the end of the file? Or do you want the lines between the 2 numbers instead of before the first and after the second? [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Comment: @Mike James, tail usually counted from the end of the file.  For you example `tail -3` means the last 3 lines of the file but the script is not doing that.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in the commants you will need to use `FNR` instead of `NR`, but you also need to pass the rest of the arguments to awk:

```
#!/bin/bash
h=$1
t=$2
shift 2 # Remove first two positional variables
awk -v h="$h" -v t="$t" 'FNR<=h && FNR>=t' "$@"
```

Or with slice:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -v h="$1" -v t="$2" 'FNR<=h && FNR>=t' "${@:3}"
```

Which could also be written with sed as:

```
sed -n "${1},${2}p" "${@:3}"
```

Which will print lines between `$1` and `$2`.

Comment: @MikeJames It will slice off the two first arguments and send the rest as seperate arguments for `awk`, eg: `set a b c d; echo "${@:3}"` will expand to `echo 'c' 'd'`.

Comment: Sorry, it works but incorrect, it outputs another lines, which are not supposed to be there. I Have two files sampledata, sampledata1, head -5, tail -3, the output should be 6 lines, right? This variant outputs much more lines ): What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the first 5 lines and last 3 lines of the files.  For tail you need to start counting from the end of the file.  If you're interested only few lines you can do it as follows (I used 3 and 2)

```
$ awk -v h=3 -v t=2 'function pr() {for(i=j;i<j+t;i++) print p[i%t];j=0}
                  NR!=FNR && FNR==1{pr()} 
                             FNR<=h;
                                   {p[j]=$0;j=(j+1)%t} 
                                END{pr()}' <(seq 10) <(seq 7)
1
2
3
9
10
1
2
3
6
7
```